# How to generate LINQ2SQL classes from T4 Templates using Fluent Hibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, t4, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, sharp-architecture

I have asked a [**similar question before**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8962142/335105)  which was not answered, i am trying to understand how can i generate LINQ2SQL classes  using T4 templates. I'm using (or trying to use) sharp architecture. just couldn't find the starting point.

What i have done: i have gone through many tutorials blogs that describe code generation using the T4 templates but couldn't find a way how can i generate the entity classes or linq2sql classes from the database like its done in the Entity Framework. Do i have to hand write the mappings and then the classes will be generated using the database or what if my question seems vague or not properly phrased, sorry for that but  thats all i have of T4 and Fluent Hibernate at the moment.

I'll be grateful for any guidance/help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sharp architecture is using NHibernate under the covers. I don't think it supports Linq2Sql as well. Either use Linq2Sql ([Getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398.aspx)) or sharp architecutre.

Comment: tnx for replying, so if i use the sharp architecture i have to write the mapping and the domain classes by hand there is no tool that will generate the domain classes using the database like its done in entity framework or the linq2sql

Answer (score 1):

LLBLGen can generate Linq2Sql from a relational data model, [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) would get you going quickly.